# How to use ng-repeat in Menu tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have below code . I create an object in javascript file and now i use this in menu by ng-repeat.

```html
<menu id="html5menu" style="display:none" class="showcase" ng-repeat="X in models">
  
  <command label="{{X.name}}" icon="{{X.icon}}" ng-click="alert('rotate')">

</menu>
```

but it not recognized ng-repeat for this tag and i get 'ng-repeat is not valid attribute of element command ,but if i use it in tr td tags right worked for me. possible use ng-repeat in menu tag ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Did you maybe mean: `<command ng-repeat="X in models" label="{{X.name}}" icon="{{X.icon}}" ng-click="alert('rotate')">`?

Comment: @FrankerZ yes ,I edit it and in addition i use visual studio 2015.

Comment: better wrap menu in a container using ngrepeat, menu is a directive and ngrepeat also contain logic, if u really want u can dig more on directive, for example priority,terminal,https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @YanjunLin your link dos'nt work.

Comment: it's angular doc for directive and use ctr+F u can find priority description, when multiple directive on same element, priority controls the sequence, first init ng-repeat or menu is a problem, make menu lower and do not terminate, maybe they will work on same element